# Filter a calendar in view

Tags: sharepoint-online, calendar-view

I have a simple list on SharePoint online. The list is called "Booking" which have Title, StartTime, EndTime and Resources column. It stored the booking of each resources.

I want to create a Calendar view for each type of resources. However, when I create a calendar view or edit the view, I am NOT allowed to add any filter or condition (e.g. Resources=Computer) other than Title, StartTime, EndTime .

How can I work around it without using SPFX?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify filters by using the classic UI for editing views.

1. Create the view using the UI already shown in your question
2. Go to list settings
3. Under views, select the calendar view you wish to amend
4. Add your filters and then click "OK" to save

Comment: Thanks! Couldn't believe it is so easy.